# Rally SDK 2.0 Ext.DomHelper

Tags: javascript, rally

I'm using the Rally SDK 2.0 to present a report and I need some custom html in it.

I looked at the docs and found the DomHelper (https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/api/Ext.DomHelper), which looks like it should do the trick, but I get the following error when I try to run the sample code.
Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

sdk-debug.js:147611

> Error: success callback for Deferred transformed result of Deferred
>   transformed result of Deferred threw: TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'insertAdjacentHTML' of null
>       at constructor.insertHtml (sdk-debug.js:14995)
>       at constructor.doInsert (sdk-debug.js:14957)
>       at constructor.append (sdk-debug.js:12905)
>       at constructor.launch (App.js?_dc=0.3312545995932721:11)
>       at constructor._applyDefaultSettingsAndLaunch (sdk-debug.js:155148)
>       at constructor.loadSettingsAndLaunch (sdk-debug.js:155054)
>       at constructor.initComponent (sdk-debug.js:155032)
>       at constructor (sdk-debug.js:30211)
>       at constructor.callParent (sdk-debug.js:4469)
>       at constructor [as _componentConstructor] (sdk-debug.js:34291)

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
componentCls: 'app',
launch: function() {
    //Write app code here
    var dh = Ext.DomHelper; // create shorthand alias
    // create the node
    var list = dh.append('my-div', {tag: 'ul', cls: 'my-list'});
    // get template
    var tpl = dh.createTemplate({tag: 'li', id: 'item{0}', html: 'List Item {0}'});
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        tpl.append(list, [i]); // use template to append to the actual node
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that at the point that launch is called your app has not actually rendered into the dom.  What if you move your code from launch into a template method like afterRender instead?

Additionally, I usually don't use DomHelper much.  Your app is an instance of Ext.Container, and it's usually easiest to just add components to yourself and let Ext handle the underlying dom interactions.

This guide in the docs may be helpful:
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/add_content

Comment: Thanks, my code sample was probably similified too much - I did have the DomHelper later on after the DOM was created, but I moved it there for illustration. Anyway, I got much further using a panel instead.